# Conditional Independence two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, independence

$X, Y$ and $Z$ are all random variables.

By definition, $P(X=x|Z=z)=P(X=x)$ implies that $X \perp Z$.

Does $P(X=x|Y=y,Z=z)=P(X=x|Y=y)$ also imply that $X \perp Z$?

Comment: What is $P(X)$ for a random *variable*?

Comment: @zhoraster what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The random variables $X$ and $Z$ are independent *conditionally* on $Y$, which does not imply independence. The simplest counterexample is $X = X' + Y$ and $Z = Z' + Y$, where $X',Z',Y$ are independent $\mathrm{Bernoulli}(\frac12)$.